# How to create a start menu icon entry (on normal Windows) for the executable downloaded in the WSLg Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I downloaded a Jetbrains Toolbox app following this instructions: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html#toolbox

In short, I did this:

Downloaded tar.gz file

Ran this: `sudo tar -xzf jetbrains-toolbox-1.17.7391.tar.gz -C /opt`

And after cd into /opt/... folder to execute, I did this: `./jetbrains-toolbox`

Windows 10 Insider dev build for WSLg allows Ubuntu Apps inside WSLg to have an entry in Start Menu of normal windows. So If I installed `sudo apt install firefox` in WSL, Firefox icon will show up in Start menu of normal Windows.

How to do the same for executable script like `./jetbrains-toolbox`?

Comment: I don't have WSLg installed, so I can't try this out, but I would guess that the Start menu entries that you mention are Shortcuts pointing to some invocation of `wsl`.  Try figuring out what WSLg is using as a commandline in those shortcuts, and you should be able to create your own.  (1) In File Explorer, go to `%appdata%/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu`, (2) find the Firefox link you mentioned, (3) right-click on it and choose "Properties".  What's the "target"?  You should be able to create one for Jetbrains using the same syntax.

Comment: I am using WIndows11 Beta and I do not see any icons. So this feature might not be stable... Anyway in my experience following the instructions above is not enough. Try using this script, it ensures that jetbrains toolbox can be executed from the terminal https://github.com/nagygergo/jetbrains-toolbox-install

Answer (score 5):

The way to add WSL programs/scripts to your windows start menu is to add an entry to the `/usr/share/applications` directory in your WSL install.

So in your example, if we create the file `/usr/share/applications/toolbox.desktop`, and add this content to the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Jetbrains Toolbox
Exec=/opt/jetbrains-toolbox
```

When you save the file, you'll have a new windows entry called `Jetbrains Toolbox (Ubuntu)`, assuming your WSL installation is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create the shortcut manually. To do so, create a new entry shortcut in

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\[WSL_NAME]
```

were `[WSL_NAME]` is the name of the target wsl installation (e.g. `Ubuntu-20.04`). Set `Start in` to `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, enter the desired name, select an appropriate icon and enter

```
C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe ~ -d Ubuntu-20.04 [EXECUTABLE_PATH]
```

as the `target`. To create a shortcut to Pycharm 2021.2.1 installed in `/opt` for example, the `[EXECUTABLE_PATH]` would be `/opt/pycharm-2021.2.1/bin/pycharm.sh`.

Comment: I had to open the directory in Powershell as Administrator and the following path:

`C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

The given path `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs[WSL_NAME]` did not exist.