# Start menu shortcut on Windows for WSL2 GUI app not working

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, wslg

I am not able to get a custom start menu shortcut to a WSL2 GUI app working inside Windows 11. The app in question is Android Studio which is installed with snap using https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie. Other installed apps that automatically creates the shortcut works (for example GIMP).

The current shortcut in Windows that is not launching Android Studio is `C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe ~ -d Ubuntu android-studio`. I am following this answer for creating the shortcut https://superuser.com/a/1672462/1096949.

Is there anything special with launching apps installed with snap? Android studio can be launched inside WSL with the `android-studio` command.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you just installing it for Windows? You need to provide the full path to the executable

Comment: I prefer the WSL2 environment when doing development and in my case it works great without any drawbacks than doing it on the Windows side. Back to my question, how can I get the full path to the executable? `/snap/bin/android-studio` seems to be a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/snap` and not to anything Android Studio specific?

Comment: There has to be an extendable otherwise it wouldn't run. My guess would be within perhaps within /bin contained within `/usr/bin/snap`. Instead of the path to the executable try `snap run android-studio`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ironically, I just read this today.  I don't use Genie myself, but I was perusing the Readme in preparation for perhaps giving it a shot.

Note a couple of important pieces of the [Genie readme](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie):

> NOTE: Before you install genie for the first time, read ALL of this page.

;-)

And at the bottom of the page:

> ##### [BUGS](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie#bugs)
>
> Linux GUI apps started from the Windows Start Menu items created by WSLg will run outside the bottle.

In other words, when you attempt to launch Android Studio via the automatically created shortcut, it launches you into a WSL session where:

- Systemd is *not* PID1
- Thus Snap cannot run
- Thus Android Studio, installed from Snap, will not work.

You *might* be able to get it working by editing the `wslg.exe` launch command with some of the insight from [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie/wiki/%22Open-a-linux-shell%22-and-genie), but I cannot be sure.

Comment: I read everything but must have forgotten that part haha. Thanks anyway, that answers my question as to why the shortcut does not work. Will experiment with the wslg executable.